# How to force show MasterViewController in Portrait mode on iPad using UISplitViewController iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm making the app with `UISplitViewController` but the it require show only the `MasterViewController` on Portrait mode in Ipad (work same as the Portrait mode on iPhone). In the landscape mode, it works normally.

Please give me some idea to make it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code in app delegate class

```
 -(id)getTopViewController{


           UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

            while (topController.presentedViewController) {
                topController = topController.presentedViewController;
            }
            if (![topController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

                return topController;
            }



    }


- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{



      UIViewController *viewOb = [self getTopViewController];


    if ([viewOb isKindOfClass:[MasterViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;


    }



    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need to show MasterViewController when Ipad in Portrait mode not force the app run on Portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `viewWillAppear`

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt: UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese use this code it will be help you out

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    //disable rotation
    return YES;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //allow only portrait interface orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not help. I want to show the MasterViewController not both (MasterViewController and DetailViewController) in Portrait mode when running on iPad. Do you have any idea for this?